# swipelistener is not working

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

i want to implement a **swipelistener** to my activity

i just implemented a **swipelistener** in my new activity(intro). which contain an image view, but when i open that it crashes , i don't know where is the error. please help me, *here is my code...*

```
package com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Intro extends AppCompatActivity {


public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}



ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(Intro.this) {
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            Toast.makeText(Intro.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(Intro.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Toast.makeText(Intro.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Toast.makeText(Intro.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

}
}
```

Comment: nee chumma copy paste chyathadeyy, (please don't simply copy and run !!

Comment: Athe.. pinnentha cheyyende

Comment: Njan padichu varunnathe ollu... So

Comment: add your logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

You need put this into `onCreate` method